# Join de tablas compuestas

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, join

Necesito crear un join compuesto y la verdad que no doy con el resultado esperado.
Tengo 3 tablas
Tabla Marcas
Tabla Autos
Tabla Operaciones

Tabla 1:
mar_codigo
mar_nombre

Tabla 2:
au_codigo
au_marca
au_nombre

Tabla 3:
ope_codigo
ope_auto
ope_marca

Como veran la clave de cada operacion es la marca-auto, ya intente lo siguiente

```
public function scopeNuevos($query){
    $data = $this
    ->join('marca', 'stoauto.sa_marca', '=', 'marca.mar_codigo')
    ->join('auto','stoauto.sa_auto','=','auto.au_codigo')
    ->select('sa_codigo','mar_nombre','sa_tipo','mar_codigo','au_nombre','au_codigo')
    ->where('sa_tipo',10);

    return $data;
}
```

Pero como resultado me trae el mismo auto con 2 marcas distintas. Hay alguna forma como de concatenar las 2 claves??
O al menos construir la consulta en lenguaje SQL, pero ya intente y no logro hacerlo.

Como podria generar la relacion en la tabla de operaciones?
Necito obtener el auto a partir de la marca y el auto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta así como el resultado esperado

Comment: Acabo de agregar una explicacion. Lo que necesito es obtener la marca y el auto correcto en la tabla de operaciones

Comment: ¿Y cual sería el campo que relaciona a las tres tablas?, entiendo que lo que ocurre acá es un cartesiano, y eso es simplemente porque no estás relacionando a todas las tablas correctamente.

Comment: Claro, el que creo la estructura de la base no siguio ninguna convencion. No hay una tabla de relaciones para las 3 tablas, lo que necesito es obtener la marca y el auto correcto en la tabla operaciones